# NiFi XMLReader Record Component sometimes ignores empty XML Elements

Tags: java, xml, apache-nifi

I am currently developing a processor for Apache NiFi that is contingent upon being configured with an implementation of `RecordReaderFactory` that produces well-formed NiFi Records based on input data.

The `JsonTreeReader` component produced accurate results for all of my test cases.  However, I noticed that, at least with the default configuration, the `XMLReader` component sometimes seems to mishandle data; namely, empty XML elements that are sub-children of XML elements that are represented as Arrays in NiFi Records.

This occurs when I test using the standard `ConvertRecord` NiFi Processor and set the Reader to `XMLReader` and the Writer to `JsonRecordSetWriter`.

These first 2 test cases work as expected:

**Test Case 1:**

Input XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
   <DataArr>SomeData</DataArr>
   <DataArr>
      <Field>
         <NonEmptyField>2</NonEmptyField>
      </Field>
   </DataArr>
</Root>
```

Output Json:

```
[
   {
      "DataArr":[
         "SomeData",
         "MapRecord[{Field=MapRecord[{NonEmptyField=2}]}]"
      ]
   }
]
```

**Test Case 2:**

Input XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
   <SomeData />
   <MoreData>2</MoreData>
</Root>
```

Output Json:

```
[
   {
      "SomeData":null,
      "MoreData":2
   }
]
```

However, the following does *not* work as expected:

**Test Case 3:**

Input XML:

```xml
<Root>
   <DataArr>SomeData</DataArr>
   <DataArr>
      <Field>
         <EmptyField/>
      </Field>
   </DataArr>
</Root>
```

Output Json:

```
[
   {
      "DataArr":[
         "SomeData"
      ]
   }
]
```

It is critical for the functioning of my Processor that Field and EmptyField appear in this Json output for Test Case 3, and for all other inputs analogous to this case.

I have tried to supply a custom NiFi RecordSchema to the components and verified it was being used, but I got the same results.

Is there a way to configure these controllers such that this empty field is not ignored, or is this a bug in the XMLReader component?

You can get these results from running this processor as described on NiFi, but you can also run this JUnit test with `testXml` swapped out with the particular test case:

```java
import org.apache.nifi.controller.ControllerService;
import org.apache.nifi.json.JsonRecordSetWriter;
import org.apache.nifi.processor.Relationship;
import org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ConvertRecord;
import org.apache.nifi.reporting.InitializationException;
import org.apache.nifi.util.MockFlowFile;
import org.apache.nifi.util.TestRunner;
import org.apache.nifi.util.TestRunners;
import org.apache.nifi.xml.XMLReader;
import org.junit.Test;

public class TestNiFiMinimal {
    @Test
    public void testEmptyXMLGetsProcessed() throws InitializationException {
        ConvertRecord convertRecord = new ConvertRecord();
        TestRunner testRunner = TestRunners.newTestRunner(convertRecord);
        ControllerService xmlReader = new XMLReader();
        testRunner.addControllerService("xmlReader", xmlReader);
        testRunner.enableControllerService(xmlReader);
        testRunner.setProperty("record-reader", "xmlReader");
        ControllerService jsonWriter = new JsonRecordSetWriter();
        testRunner.addControllerService("jsonWriter", jsonWriter);
        testRunner.enableControllerService(jsonWriter);
        testRunner.setProperty("record-writer", "jsonWriter");
        String testXml = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Root><DataArr>SomeData</DataArr><DataArr><Field><EmptyField/></Field></DataArr></Root>";
        testRunner.enqueue(testXml);
        testRunner.run();
        Relationship success = convertRecord.getRelationships().stream().filter(relationship -> relationship.getName().equals("success")).findAny().get();
        testRunner.assertAllFlowFilesTransferred(success);
        final MockFlowFile original = testRunner.getFlowFilesForRelationship(success).get(0);
        original.assertContentEquals("");
    }
}
```

This is the configuration of the XMLReader component that I use when testing on the GUI - this produces the exact same results and has all the default configuration options:

[image: Image of the XMLReader configuration]

Comment: you have 2 elements with the same name in xml: `DataArr` - i think the problem is here.

Comment: That fact is true both in Test Case 1 and Test Case 3.  Besides, I don’t take your point - an XML element is allowed to have children of the same name, and this controller is aware of this fact.  They are manifested as arrays, which is the entire point.  I am having unexpected behavior related to subchildren of XML elements that manifest as arrays in NiFi records @daggett

Comment: right. could you show the parameters of xml reader?

Comment: @daggett Sure, but it's all the default configurations.  Hence the same results happen on the GUI as the ones in the JUnit